# Toggle <p:panel> depending on selected value of <p:selectOneRadio>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to toggle a hidden panel when a user select a specific radio button.
Using latest version of primefaces.

For instance:

```
<p:panel id="panel1" visible="false" widgetVar="firePanel" closable="true" toggleable="true">
 hello
</p:panel>

<p:selectOneRadio value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}" layout="pageDirection">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="opt1" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="opt2" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="opt"/>                           
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I would like to achieve something like this, but when clicking RadioButton3, not using a commandButton

```
<p:commandButton id="but" value="Show" onclick="firePanel.show();"/>
```

Is that even possible?
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the following steps :

1. declare a `boolean` variable in your backing bean to manage the state of the panel and bind it to the `visible` attribute of the panel

   ```
   boolean panelIsVisible;
   //getter and setter
   ```

   ```html
   <p:panel id="panel1" visible="#{formBean.panelIsVisible}" widgetVar="firePanel" closable="true" toggleable="true">
   ```
2. define a method  to toggle the value of the visibility boolean based on the value of `selectedOptions`

   ```
   public void changePanelState(){

       //set panelIsVisible to true or false based on whatever conditions you choose

   }
   ```
3. Add the `<p:ajax/>` event to your `<p:selectOneRadio/>` to fire ajax events on any select on that menu

   ```
   <p:selectOneRadio value="#{formBean.selectedOptions}" layout="pageDirection">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="opt1" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="opt2" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="opt"/> 
     <p:ajax listener="#{formBean.changePanelState}" update="panel1"/>                          
   </p:selectOneRadio>
   ```

   This is assuming that `panel1` is in the same `<h:form/>` as the selectOneRadio.

Comment: You can also use `visible="#{formBean.selectedOptions == 'opt'}"` without the need for an extra property and a listener.

Comment: Thanks @kolossus & BalusC. It worked as expected and really helped a lot. Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately it only works the 1st time I run the page. If I get any validation errors after trying to submit the form, the ajax call stop working. Any advice on that @BalusC. thanks